# Column resize order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

Using Bootstrap 3 I'd like to get this resize functionality:

On smaller screens:

```
------------
| TitleBar |
------------
| NavBar   |
------------
|          |
| Content  |
|          |
------------
```

On larger screens:

```
----------------------
| NavBar | TitleBar  |
|        |------------
|        |           |
|        | Content   |
|        |           |
----------------------
```

The closest I've been able to get, from the following example, produces this result:

```
----------------------
| NavBar | TitleBar  |
|        |------------
|        |           
|        |    
|        |           
----------------------
         |           |
         | Content   |
         |           |
         -------------



<div id="voterRegistrationContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="TitleBar" class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-2" style="background-color:turquoise">                    
            Voter Registration
        </div>

        <div id="NavBar" class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-10" style="background-color:lightblue;"">
            <ul style="font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large; list-style: none">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Voters</li>
                <li>Register</li>
                <li>Elections</li>
                <li>Reports</li>
                <li>Admin</li>
                <li>Log Out</li>
            </ul>
        </div>                   

        <div id="Content" class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-2" style="background-color:lavender;">
            This is where the content goes
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure Bootstrap can't do that...floats don't work that way. Could be interesting though.

Comment: Yeah, it was given to me as a requirement but I'm not certain there is an easy way to do it in Bootstrap, unless I'm overlooking something.  It may be possible to have two TitleBars;  one that is present on smaller screens but hides on larger screens and the other that is only on the larger screens.

Comment: Flexbox can do it but that's about the only way and even then it's messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this with Bootstrap is to use the `pull-right` class since your "nav" is taller that your "title", Bootstrap will naturally float the "nav" to the left. Therefore, you can use `pull-right` to keep the "title" and "content" on the right. Again, this works under the *assumption* that your **"nav" is taller than your "title"**...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 pull-right">
          Voter Registration
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <ul style="font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large; list-style: none">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Voters</li>
            <li>Register</li>
            <li>Elections</li>
            <li>Reports</li>
            <li>Admin</li>
            <li>Log Out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 pull-right">
          This is where the content goes
      </div>
   </div>  
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/nlZB5NufX0

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking there wasn't a Bootstrap way either.

Comment: Indeed, I've worked out a flexbox solution but I think it requires a known `.row` height (at least in Chrome)

Comment: You're welcome. Interesting scenario where thinking "mobile first" doesn't work. Although, using the `col-*-pull-*`, `col-*-push-*` classes is the preferred solution. Only use `pull-right` or the responsive utility classes as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I think in something like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">TitleBar</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">NavBar</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs">TitleBar</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works too, I had a colleague suggest it and I was able to prototype and get it working this way, though using pull-right is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right structure for that:

```
<div id="voterRegistrationContainer" class="container-fluid">

    <div id="NavBar" class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color:lightblue;"">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a>Voters</a></li>
                  <li><a>Voters</a></li>
                  <li><a>Voters</a></li>
                  <li><a>Voters</a></li>
                  <li><a>Voters</a></li>
                  <li><a>Voters</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
        </div>    


        <div id="TitleBar" class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color:turquoise">                    
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Title Bar
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                Content
            </div>
        </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the OP wants the title first on mobile.